# Java Memory Usage / Thread Pool Performance Problem

Tags: java, performance, memory, visualvm, jvisualvm

These things obviously require close inspection and availability of code to thoroughly analyze and give good suggestions. Nevertheless, that is not always possible and I hope it may be possible to provide me with good tips based on the information I provide below.

I have a server application that uses a listener thread to listen for incoming data. The incoming data is interpreted into application specific messages and these messages then give rise to events.

Up to that point I don't really have any control over how things are done.

Because this is a legacy application, these events were previously taken care of by that same listener thread (largely a single-threaded application). The events are sent to a blackbox and out comes a result that should be written to disk.

To improve throughput, I wanted to employ a threadpool to take care of the events. The idea being that the listener thread could just spawn new tasks every time an event is created and the threads would take care of the blackbox invocation. Finally, I have a background thread performing the writing to disk.

With just the previous setup and the background writer, everything works OK and the throughput is ~1.6 times more than previously.

When I add the thread pool however performance degrades. At the start, everything seems to run smoothly but then after awhile everything is very slow and finally I get OutOfMemoryExceptions. The weird thing is that when I print the number of active threads each time a task is added to the pool (along with info on how many tasks are queued and so on) it looks as if the thread pool has no problem keeping up with the producer (the listener thread).

Using top -H to check for CPU usage, it's quite evenly spread out at the outset, but at the end the worker threads are barely ever active and only the listener thread is active. Yet it doesn't seem to be submitting more tasks...

Can anyone hypothesize a reason for these symptoms? Do you think it's more likely that there's something in the legacy code (that I have no control over) that just goes bad when multiple threads are added? The out of memory issue should be because some queue somewhere grows too large but since the threadpool almost never contains queued tasks it can't be that.

Any ideas are welcome. Especially ideas of how to more efficiently diagnose a situation like this. How can I get a better profile on what my threads are doing etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the blackbox a terminal component or connected? Is it a passive or active component?  And where did you get your thread pool?

Comment: Please give more details on the blackbox.

Comment: The blackbox is just an internal function that takes objects of type A and performs various operations of them to produce objects of type B. This is the computation part of the application and what the threads in the pool execute. The threadpool is the standard oracle/sun jdk implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the answers. I read up on Java VisualVM and used that as a tool. The results and conclusions are detailed below. Hopefully the pictures will work long enough.

I first ran the program and created some heap dumps thinking I could just analyze the dumps and see what was taking up all the memory. This would probably have worked except the dump file got so large and my workstation was of limited use in trying to access it. After waiting two hours for one operation, I realized I couldn't do this.

So my next option was something I, stupidly enough, hadn't thought about. I could just reduce the number of messages sent to the application, and the trend of increasing memory usage should still be there. Also, the dump file will be smaller and faster to analyze.

It turns out that when sending messages at a slower rate, no out of memory issue occured! A graph of the memory usage can be seen below.

[image: slow send]

The peaks are results of cumulative memory allocations and the troughs that follow are after the garbage collector has run. Although the amount of memory usage certainly is quite alarming and there are probably issues there, no long term trend of memory leakage can be observed.

I started to incrementally increase the rate of messages sent per second to see where the application hits the wall. The image below shows a very different scenario then the previous one...

[image: fast send]

Because this happens when the rate of messages sent are increased, my guess is that my freeing up the listener thread results in it being able to accept a lot of messages very quickly and this causes more and more allocations. The garbage collector doesn't run and the memory usage hits a wall.

There's of course more to this issue but given what I have found out today I have a fairly good idea of where to go from here. Of course, any additional suggestions/comments are welcome.

This questions should probably be recategorized as dealing with memory usage rather than threadpools... The threadpool wasn't the problem at all.

Answer (score 5):

Slowing down then out of memory implies a memory leak.

So I would start by using some Java memory analyzer tools to identify if there is a leak and what is  being leaked. Sometimes you get lucky and the leaked object is well-known and it becomes pretty clear who is hanging on to things that they should not.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @djna. 
Thread Pool of java concurrency package works. It does not create threads if it does not need them. You see that number of threads is as expected. This means that probably something in your legacy code is not ready for multithreading. For example some code fragment is not synchronized. As a result some element is not removed from collection. Or some additional elements are stored in collection. So, the memory usage is growing.

BTW I did not understand exactly which part of the application uses threadpool now. Did you have one thread that processes events and now you have several threads that do this? Have you probably changed the inter-thread communication mechanism? Added queues? This may be yet another direction of your investigation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by djna, it's likely some type of memory leak. My guess would be that you're keeping a reference to the request around somewhere:

- In the dispatcher thread that's queuing the requests
- In the threads that deal with the requests
- In the black box that's handling the requests
- In the writer thread that writes to disk.

Since you said everything works find before you add the thread pool into the mix, my guess would be that the threads in the pool are keeping a reference to the request somewhere. Th idea being that, without the threadpool, you aren't reusing threads so the information goes away.

As recommended by djna, you can use a Java memory analyzer to help figure out where the data is stacking up.